# Can a thread-local copy of select elements be created of a shared 2D array in a parallel region? (Shared, private, barrier: OPenMP)

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, barrier

I have a 2-D grid of `n`x`n` elements. In one iteration, I'm calculating the value of one element by averaging the values of its neighbors. That is:

```
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            grid[i][j] = (grid[i-1][j] + grid[i][j-1] + grid[i+1][j] + grid[i][j+1])/4.0;
```

And I need to run the above nested loop for `iter` number of iterations. 
What I need is the following:

1. I need the threads to calculate this average, wait till all the threads have finished calculating and THEN update the grid in one go.
2. The loop with `iter` iterations will run sequentially, but **during** every iteration, the value of `grid[i][j]` for every `i` and `j` should be calculated in parallel.

In order to do that I have the following ideas and questions:

1. Maybe make grid **shared** and put a copy of the select 4 elements of the grid that is needed for calculating `grid[i][j]` by making only those 4 elements **private** to the thread. (Basically grid is shared by all threads, but there is a local copy of 4 ***iteration-specific*** elements in every thread too.) **Is this possible?**
2. Would a `barrier` be in fact needed for all the threads to finish and then start onto the next iteration?

I'm very new to the OpenMP way of thinking and I'm utterly lost in this simple problem. I'd be grateful if somebody could help resolve my confusion.

Comment: currently you are calculating the average based on the neighbors of the same array and immediately write it in the current array element. This looks suspicious btw, due to depedenices. As soon as you go to parallel threads, you will have to do a very complicated synchronization scheme to let correct threads to wait for the result of other threads. i.e. update for calculation for grid[2][2] has to wait till calcuation for [1][1], [3,2] and all other neighbors are finished. and other should wait for gheir neighbors, ... Otherwise you will have undefined behavior. Is this what you want?

Comment: You should be able to find useful discussion on jacobi  iterative parallelism.  It may go beyond criticality.

Comment: for calculation of `grid[2][2]` I want to use the values of `[1][2]`, `[2][1]`, `[3][2]`, `[2][3]` of the original grid (as they were before entering this iteration). Then update grid[2][2] and other values once all the threads have finished calculating using only the old values of the grid. Then start another iteration using only the newly obtained values of the grid. @Serge

Comment: A simple way is to just save all your work to a second grid.  When your calculations are all done you can swap grid and grid2.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I thought of that, but in case of massive amounts of data, won't that be inefficient w.r.t memory? I was trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: Inefficient how?  Memory?  You need 2 copies, which you'll need anyway.  It can be OpenMP friendly, and the post loop update can be very quick when handled the right way (swapping pointers).

Comment: @complextea it does not work like this in your example. You use average values previously calculated in other iterations. You **need** a second array to keep the results. In this case you can use threads for every iteration without any need for synchronization (except for 'join'). Most likely it would be an overkill. You need to define just a few of them , i.e. 8 and reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In practice, you'd want to have (much) fewer threads than grid points, so each thread will be calculating a whole bunch of points (for example, one row). There is a certain overhead associated with starting OpenMP (or any other kind of) threads, and you program will be memory-bound rather than CPU-bound anyway. So starting a thread per grid point will defeat the whole purpose of parallelizing the computation. Hence, your idea #1 is not recommended (I am not quite sure I understood it correctly though; maybe this is not what you were proposing).
2. I would recommend (also pointed out by others in OP comments) you allocate twice the memory needed to store the grid values and use two pointers that are swapped between iterations: one points to memory holding previous iteration values that are read only, the other one to new iteration values that are write-only. Note that you will only swap the pointers, not actually copy the memory. After your iteration is done, you can copy the final result into desired location.
3. Yes, you need to synchronize threads between iterations, however in OpenMP this is usually done implicitly simply by opening a parallel region within the iteration loop (there is an implicit barrier at the end of a parallel region):

   ```
   for (int iter = 0; iter < niter; ++iter)
   {
       #pragma omp parallel
       {
           // get range of points for current thread
           // loop over thread's points and apply the stencil
       }
   }
   ```

   or, using a `parallel for` construct:

   ```
   const int np = n*n;
   for (int iter = 0; iter < niter; ++iter)
   {
       #pragma omp parallel for
       for (int ip = 0; ip < np; ++ip)
       {
           const int i = ip / n;
           const int j = ip % n;
           // apply the stencil to [i,j]
       }
   }
   ```

   The second version will auto-distribute the work evenly between the available threads, which is most likely what you want. In the first you have to do it manually.

Comment: I just wanted to ask one more doubt with regard to your answer. Do you mean to say that the second version will auto-distribute because of the for directive present in the second version and absent in the first?

Comment: @complextea pretty much, yeah. When the compiler sees the `parallel for` construct, it sets loop conditions for each thread appropriately. There are different scheduling modes, but default one usually means just "spread work equally". A simple `parallel` region just means "execute this code in every thread", and then it's up to the programmer to figure out the piece of work to be done, e.g. using OpenMP thread number. This is sometimes desirable, when workload distribution is more complicated than a single 'for' loop.